# Is there way to get ObjectGUID from `LDAPResult ` object?

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid

I have a code like this for user creation:

```
AddRequest addRequest = new AddRequest(...
...
LDAPResult addResult = ldapConnectionPool.add(addRequest)
```

Is there way to get [ObjectGUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/using-objectguid-to-bind-to-an-object) from `addResult` field ?

Or maybe there is a way to generate this `ObjectGUID` on the client side and send as an argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with basic LDAP – 'Add' operation results do not return any data from the server to client, only a success/error code.

There are LDAP extensions, namely the "postRead" control, that would allow this – an add/modify operation with the postRead control would return the whole resulting entry – but Active Directory does not support them. (I think only OpenLDAP does.) As you're talking about ObjectGUID rather than entryUUID, I assume you're using AD rather than OpenLDAP.

So you will need to make a separate search for the DN that you just added and retrieve the objectGUID that way.

Comment: Actually my backend is Samba. 

What is your opinion about performance ? we will need to make additional Ldap request every time we create an entry

Comment: Samba is still AD; it doesn't use OpenLDAP (it implements its own LDAP server), and as far as I know, it does not implement any LDAP extensions that MS AD doesn't have.

Comment: As for performance, if it's just one entry, live with it; if it's multiple entries, use async operations (pipelining) – issue a bunch of add operations at once and collect their results; issue a bunch of search operations and collect results. (And, suggest your Samba server admins to consider switching the DB backend to LMDB – it's said that it offers much better performance than Samba's traditional tdb/LDB.)